# in vimrc apply certain highlighting rules only for certain filetype

Tags: vim, file-type

in my vimrc I have a script that transform a text in bold when banded between * * double stars * * (like it does in this editor actually), but i don't want it to apply on my js or c or any programming files of course, so i tried to make it run only when it's a .txt file :

```
if (&filetype=='text')
    set concealcursor=n
    set conceallevel=3
    hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
    autocmd BufEnter * syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal
    autocmd BufEnter * syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*.*\*\*" contains=Asterisks
endif
```

but obviously the condition of the "if" doesn't work since this rules doesn't apply anymore in none of my file, text or not

EDIT => SOLUTION

after reading the answers I choose this solution, in my vimrc (even though it's not the best way vim works as explaind by ingo)

```
au BufEnter *.txt setf text "(set a filetype unless it already exist)
au filetype text set cocu=n cole=3
au filetype text hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
au filetype text syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal
au filetype text syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*.*\*\*" contains=Asterisks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an `augroup`.

See `:help augroup` and `:help filetype`.

For instance:

```
augroup asteriskbold
    au!
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.md,*.mkd,*.markdown,*.mdwn set concealcursor=n conceallevel=3
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.md,*.mkd,*.markdown,*.mdwn hi AsteriskBold ctermfg=Green cterm=bold
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.md,*.mkd,*.markdown,*.mdwn syn match Asterisks contained "**" conceal
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.md,*.mkd,*.markdown,*.mdwn syn match AsteriskBold "\*\*.*\*\*" contains=Asterisks
augroup end
```

Comment: You're duplicating the _filetype detection_ needlessly. If the OP already has that set up for a `text` filetype, you can simple hop on top of that and use `au FileType text`. Note that I would still prefer the (built-in) filetype plugins over this approach.

Comment: Ok! Thanks Ingo!

Comment: for the moment I like to put all my settings in my vimrc because I don't have a lot of settings and I often work on new computers so it's easy to save my vimrc and have all my settings in one place

Answer (score 8):

#### Filetypes

Filetype-specific settings go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/text.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType text ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

#### Syntaxes

For `:syntax` commands, there's a corresponding directory `~/.vim/after/syntax/text.vim`. (Vim currently doesn't ship with a dedicated `text` syntax; you could drop the `after` part, and make your syntax the main one.)

By syntax script convention, your syntax groups should be prefixed with the filetype; e.g. `textAsterisks`. The `:hi` group has to be renamed as well; however, usually syntax scripts use `:hi def link` to link the syntax group to a (more generic) highlight group: `hi def link textAsteriskBold AsteriskBold`. More information at the end of [`usr_44.txt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_44.txt.html#usr_44.txt).

#### Highlight groups

These are global, you can put your `:hi` command(s) directly into your `~/.vimrc` and define it just once.

#### Conceal

The conceal settings are *window-local*, but filetypes and syntaxes apply to *buffers*. And by using `:set` (instead of `:setlocal`), those settings will be inherited by any new window opened from the one that shows a text file. Depending on your workflow (and whether other filetypes you edit use concealing at all), you may never notice this, and there's no good workaround (only a huge mess of `:autocmd` could try to adapt those). Just be aware of this.

Comment: very interesting ! I don't mark it as the accepted answer though because it doesn't immediately solve my issue, but gives informations on how things actually works

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to teach you, not to give you ready-made answers you just need to copy-and-paste. (Especially as your question can be solved on different levels, with varying effort.) But sure, you can wait some more time :-)

Comment: sure, but in the same time, i learned about the augroup command and that my syntax was incorrect with the if statement, and i still need to figure out by myself why augroup is needed since each aucommand line begin with the verification of the filetype, so it's not quite a ready to use answer, and i feel it's closer to my exact question, but then i have read your post very carefully to use it in the future, it's really helpful